# recent songs are showing up in files but not on music apps

Tags: applications, music, music-player, google-play-music

Recently when I download new songs onto my droid RAZR maxx they appear in my files in the music folder along with all of my other songs, but don't show in the music app. I have checked all over the internet to figure out what's wrong but have seen nothing. I cleared cache, I checked to make sure there weren't any weird symbols in the title, I refreshed music app, I uninstalled and reinstalled music app, I tried a different music app. Again the file can be played through file manager using the music app but when I look through the music app itself its not there, I have tried looking to see of it might be under a different name as well. I use the Google play music app.

Comment: can you mention the path where you have stored the songs?

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it. I've solved the problem before by clearing all my music data (files and everything), and just replacing them, but that is a painful prospect, and really should only be used as a final resort.